# Total number of “hyperconjugable” hydrogens in 1-(3-ethyl-4-methylphenyl)-2-methylprop-1-ylium

Tags: organic-chemistry, hyperconjugation

How do I find the total number of “hyperconjugable” structures for 1-(3-ethyl-4-methylphenyl)-2-methylprop-1-ylium?

[image: 1-(3-ethyl-4-methylphenyl)-2-methylprop-1-ylium]

I read some sources stating that the total number of “hyperconjugable” structures is equal to the total number of α-hydrogen atoms. But which carbon is taken as the alpha carbon in a compound having no functional groups, just carbons?

Comment: How many hydrogens "contribute to hyperconjugation" is more understandable phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

There is one obvious $\alpha$-position, which is the tertiary carbon atom adjacent to the carbon carrying positive charge. This contributes one hypercongujation structure. It looks like there are no more apparent structures, but the methyl group that is *para* to the cation can also participate in hyperconjugation

[image: hyperconjugation structure]

There are three $\ce{H}$-atoms on the methyl group, which give us three more structures. Thus, there are a total of **4** hyperconjugable hydrogens in this structure.

Interesting to note is that the ethyl group at the *meta* position does not participate in hyperconjugation. Can you find a reason why?